# Multiple Wix Installers from the same Solution

Tags: wix

There is a Solution (.net, c#) which has 2 projects inside.

- a C# web project
- a C# project - Windows service

Both of them will need a separate Wix installer. (Wix installer for the web app, and Wix installer for the Windows Service)

How should this be approached? We built the Web installer, using a new Wix Setup Project added to the Solution. Should we create a new Wix Setup Project for the Windows Service as well? Having 2 Wix Setup Projects in the same Solution? Or can this Wix Setup Project be re-used somehow?

Should we consider trying to create somehow an installer that has both of them (both applications) and the user who is in charge of installing would check one or both checkboxes during install?

Comment: As far as I know, there is no option to have multiple installers in 1 project, so you need 2 projects, or, as you said, one with selectable features. I would probably used solution with multiple projects, if web project and service are not commonly installed together, because you can better control distribution of you software and installer is smaller.

Comment: You might also consider adding a WiX Bootstrapper if you have more than one WiX Setup.

Comment: @Mischo5500 If you want to add this answer, I will Accept it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"As far as I know, there is no option to have multiple installers in 1 project, so you need 2 projects, or, as you said, one with selectable features. I would probably used solution with multiple projects, if web project and service are not commonly installed together, because you can better control distribution of you software and installer is smaller."

by @Mischo5500